# Getting issue on adding multiple signature fields in the PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am adding multiple signature fields in the document using iText7.
My scenario is as follows:

Add 1 signature field in the document and sign the document. That signature is verified in the Adobe.
Add 2nd signature field in the same document and sign the document again. Upon opening the document in Adobe, the last signature is verified but following error is shown on already signed signature field:

**Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data. Support Information: SigDict / Contents illegal data**

The code snippet for adding signature field into PDF is as follows:

```
using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (PdfReader _pdfReader = new PdfReader(new 
MemoryStream(_documentBytes)).SetUnethicalReading(true))
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(_pdfReader, new PdfWriter(memoryStream)))
{
PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
foreach (PDFSignatureField field in signatureFields)
{
//Initializing signature position object
PDFSignaturePosition SigPosition = field.Position;
for (int i = 0; i < SigPosition.Pages.Length; ++i)
{
//Getting PDF document page
PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(SigPosition.Pages[i]);
if (page == null)
{
page = pdfDocument.GetPage(SigPosition.PageNumber);
}
//Getting PDF document page rotation
int rotation = page.GetRotation();
//Getting signature field rects according to PDF page
iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect;
if (rotation > 0 && SigPosition.Position == PDFSignaturePosition.DefaultSignaturePosition.Custom)
{
rect = GetSignaturePositionAccordingToRotation(SigPosition.Rect, page.GetCropBox(), rotation);
}
else
{
rect = GetSignaturePositionRect(SigPosition.Position, SigPosition.Rect, page.GetCropBox());
}
//Creating signature field into PDF page
PdfFormField sig = PdfSignatureFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDocument, rect); 
//PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDocument, rect);

//Setting signature field visible flag
if (field.Display == (int)SignatureDisplayType.INVISIBLE)
{
sig.SetFieldFlags(PdfFormField.HIDDEN);
sig.SetVisibility(PdfFormField.HIDDEN);
}
else
{
sig.SetFieldFlags(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
sig.SetVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
}
//Setting signature field name
sig.SetFieldName(i == 0 ? field.Name : field.Name + " - " + SigPosition.Pages[i]);
//Setting signature field page
sig.SetPage(SigPosition.Pages[i]);
//Adding signature field into AcroForm
pdfAcroForm.AddField(sig);
pdfAcroForm.AddFieldAppearanceToPage(sig, page);
pdfAcroForm.SetDefaultAppearance("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g");
//Making indirect reference of the added signature field into PDF
sig.MakeIndirect(pdfDocument);
}
//Closing PDF document object
pdfDocument.Close();
//Getting latest document bytes after adding PDF field
documentBytes = ((MemoryStream)memoryStream).ToArray();
_documentBytes = documentBytes;
}
}
```

Could anyone help me regarding this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` mode to make iText create incremental updates instead of creating a new document from scratch. I.e. use

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(_pdfReader, new PdfWriter(memoryStream), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode())
```

Comment: I have used the above solution which resolved my issue. Thanks.
But there is another issue caused due to above solution. I am using custom signature appearance in my current implementation. It was working fine but after adding the above solution my signature appearance goes blank. The issue I have identified is that the root area of layer2 becomes 0.
Could you please guide me in this scenario.
Regards

Comment: You most likely will have to update your code to mark changed objects accordingly. I'll try to look into that tomorrow or Friday

Comment: In further investigation I found that the Invisible signature is created in above case. Is there any property needed to be set for making it visible after using the above solution.
Regards

Comment: @MuddassirAwan *"I am using custom signature appearance in my current implementation."* - I have looked into your code from your question but there is nothing in it generating a *custom signature appearance*. Thus, I obviously cannot help you analyzing the issue that that *signature appearance goes blank*.

Comment: Please refer to the following question. I have added the code in that as this link was related to another question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346843/itext7-converting-signature-as-an-invisible-signature-after-using-append-mode-pr

Regards